# Unity changing orthographic camera's size zooms scene view, not game view

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to zoom by changing Orthographic Camera's  value.
Though when I change it's value, changes rather occur in Scene View not in the Game View.
Canvas shown in Scene View gets bigger but there's no change in Game View.
Whether I try to zoom by code or manually in the inspector same thing happens.
Here's Image of some screenshots.

[Camera inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c3Sl.png)

[Orthographic size set to 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2tAe.png)

[Orthographic size set to 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S9oy.png)

[Canvas inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmmvO.png)

Would appreciate some help.

```
Camera.orthographicSize
```

Comment: If your sprites are within your canvas, the canvas will scale to fit the camera, therefore the scene will show that the orthographic size changed, however all the sprites are scaling with the orthographic size. One way to see the if the effect is working is to just put a sprite in the scene, outside of the canvas and see if its size changes.

Comment: @timeBenter It helped thanks a lot!